# Converting Java Regex to Javascript Regex

Tags: java, javascript, regex

I have a regular expression in java

```
^.*(?=.{8,})(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!()*,/:;<>?\\\]\[\-_`{}~@#$%^&+=]).*$
```

It matches strings which having these conditions:

- at least 8 characters
- at least one digit
- at least one small letter
- at least one capital letter
- at least one special character

  ```
  [!()*,/:;<>?\\\]\[\-_`{}~@#$%^&+=]
  ```

How can I convert it into a JavaScript regex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple solution with simple regex.

```
var re = /^(.{0,7}|\D+|[^a-z]+|[^A-Z]+|[^\^!@#$%&\*])$/;
if (!re.test(str)) {
    alert('Matched');
}
```

Note that there are some missing special characters in my regex.

Comment: It's a very good idea to see thing in negative way. But it's not giving exact result. Please see [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mabilalmirza/8QWAr/10/).

Comment: Simple solution with simple regex that doesn't work. `aaaaaaa`

Comment: @BilalMirza You should escape - sign. [updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/taggon/8QWAr/11/)

Answer (score 3):

put two forward slashes around it:

```
var re = /<your_regex_here>/;
```

Answer (score 2):

It already works in JavaScript:

```
var re = /^.*(?=.{8,})(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!()*,/:;<>?\\\]\[\-_`{}~@#$%^&+=]).*$/;
re.test('abcdefgh0A$') // true
```

Comment: I hava a created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mabilalmirza/8QWAr/). All given strings are valid but it does not match some of strings. Am I missing something there?

Comment: @BilalMirza: First, a tip: use regular expression literals, like I did in the example with slashes - never `new RegExp`, which is almost always a bad idea. Next, no, they're not all valid... `ptiLad4emp9`, for example, does not contain a symbol.

Comment: You are right. that all strings are not valid. I wonder why did I noticed that. But why **new RegExp()** is a bad idea?

Comment: @BilalMirza: Just because you have to remember to escape everything, and it's also slightly slower (think `eval`).